# Implementing a Method That Returns an Object vs. a List of that Object

Tags: java, interface

I have an interface like so:

```
public interface FruitGetter {
    public Fruit getFruit();
    public List<Fruit> getFruits(int numFruit);
}
```

Fruit is an interface that I may implement for different types of fruit.

My confusion comes from the fact that implementing the two methods above doesn't seem to be consistent:

```
@Override
public Apple getFruit(){return new Apple();}

@Override
public List<Apple> getFruits(int numFruit){ //you get the idea}
```

Can someone please explain why the second implementation is an incompatible return type, while the first method seems to work correctly?

Comment: The second way doesn't work because `List<Apple>` isn't a subtype of `List<Fruit>`.

Comment: You need a type variable on `FruitGetter`: `FruitGetter<F extends Fruit>`; use `F` in place of `Fruit` in the methods. Then implement it as `class AppleGetter implements FruitGetter<Apple>`.

Comment: Java allows for covariant return types. i.e., you can override a method with a return type that is a subtype of the original. Like `Apple` is a subtype of `Fruit`. But like Andy said, the same doesn't go for `List<Fruit>` and `List<Apple>`. You can see why here: [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p)

Comment: Thank you Andy :D